# using generator to continue looping after breaking from loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was trying to use a generator for a use case where we have to track k "largest" elements in a stream of strings. What I wanted to do is to add elements to a list till they reach element k and then heapify and then continue the stream from there using elements one by one to maintain the heap. I am a bit new to using generators so appreciate any help

```
def my_generator(stream):
    for string in stream:
        yield string
def top_k(k,stream):
    count = 0
    min_heap = []
    for string in stream:

            if count >= k:
                break
            min_heap.append((len(string),string))
            count += 1
            print(min_heap)

    heapq.heapify(min_heap)

    for string in stream:
        heapq.heappushpop(min_heap,(len(string),string))

    return  heapq.nsmallest(k,min_heap)

strings = ["This", "whatis", "going", "in"]
stream = my_generator(strings)
output = top_k(2,stream)
print(output)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your break point and subsequent resuming of the stream causes an element to be "lost" to the void.

Here's your code but without losing any element:

```py
def top_k(k, stream):
    min_heap = []

    # loop over k instead of stream
    for _ in range(k):
        string = next(stream) # get the next item
        min_heap.append((len(string), string))
        print(min_heap) # debug

    heapq.heapify(min_heap)

    # here we finish all of what's left in stream
    for string in stream:
        heapq.heappushpop(min_heap, (len(string), string))

    return heapq.nsmallest(k, min_heap)
```